# Convert "Wed Dec 02 24:00:00 GMT 2020" to 02/12/2020 with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date

I want to convert "Wed Dec 02 24:00:00 GMT 2020" to "02/12/2020" using VBA.

I created a custom function.

```vb
Function Get_date(CellRef As String)
    Dim Year_num As Integer, Month_name As String, Month_num As Integer, Date_num As Integer'''
    Year_num = Right(CellRef, 4)
    Month_name = Mid(CellRef, 5, 3)
    Month_num = Month(DateValue(Month_name&("1")))
    Date_num = Mid(CellRef, 9, 2)
    
    Get_date = DateSerial(Year_num, Month_num, Date_num)
    
End Function
```

Comment: What precisely isn't working? What output do you get?

Comment: I'd be surprised if 24:00:00 was a valid time: isn't that midnight the next day? Shouldn't this be 03/12/2020 not 02/12?

Comment: Your function will work with this correction:  `Month_num = Month(DateValue(Month_name & "-1"))`, if you have English months. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) about why use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Get-date = CDate(Right(CellRef, 4) & Mid(CellRef, 4, 7))
```